# ¿Cómo modificar esta propiedad visual en mis controles chart?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando la parte visual de la sección de estadísticas de mi aplicación. Mi problema es que en la misma, utilizo tonos oscuros, por lo que cambié mis `charts` a colores claros, con el inconveniente de que no consigo dar con la propiedad que me modifique los colores de los *valores X e Y* de mis controles (estuve literalmente un día entero cambiando propiedades y buscando documentación).

Hay controles que no permiten modificar ciertas partes visuales, y toca meter mucho código para modificar los colores, no sé si este sea el caso.

Adjunto una foto (resalté en rojo las partes que mencioné anteriormente):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias aclarar que controles son los que estas usando?

Comment: Se llama Chart el control (Namespace:  System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting), es el que resalte (despues con el mismo, se pueden mostrar diferentes graficas modificando sus propiedades).

Comment: Ah listo son los controles chart por defecto (te preguntaba porque a veces usan otros y no lo aclaran...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Propiedades del chart(filtra por categorías para orientarte mejor si quieres). 
   Chart > ChartAreas > abrimos el desplegable.

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Vamos al apartado Axes

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Elegimos el eje que queremos modificar X/Y, vamos a Labels > LabelStyle > Font y 
   escogemos el color que mas nos guste :)

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier duda comentalo